# WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET required for linux plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm running an Azure function on a linux premium plan (EP1). Automatic recommendations tell me to set these variables as they are essential for linux plans:

[image: Automatic recommendations]

while the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring) states

> Only used by function apps on a Consumption or Premium plans running on Windows. Not supported for Linux.

My function seems to run fine without these variables, but I feel a little unsettled about this (maybe they will not correctly scale out later?).

Can someone make it clear if these variables are required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended matrix :

•   Linux Elastic Premium/App Service - [WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentshare), [WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring) & WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE

•   Linux Consumption- WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE

The official document will be modified at the earliest to reflect the similar recommendation.

Comment: But does this also follow if you are using docker images, since the content is not served from the blob storage?